# How to set global maven distrubution management settings?

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I want to avoid putting this part in `pom.xml` of every project distributed the same way

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>my-id</id>
        <name>My deployed artifacts</name>
        <url>https://organization.xxx/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

How to set it globally via maven command or editing setting file?

Comment: Create a corporate parent which contains such configuration as well as defining each used plugin with it's version etc.. Apart from that you usually need two snapshot and release (assumed you are using snapshots)...

Comment: The `distribution` tag does not mean what you think it means. Please read tag descriptors before using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot be done in `settings.xml`.

What you can do:

- Use a company parent POM that specifies the distributionManagement.
- Set a property in the `settings.xml` and use it in distributionManagement.
- Use `-DaltDeploymentRepository=...` on command line for the build. See also https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository

Comment: Thank you! I think "altDeploymentRepository" would work accompanied by some env variables in my case.